# Display error if the email address entered in form already exists

Tags: php, mysqli

How do I use "emailaddress" as the only duplicate entry that provides a error?

A lot of the answers I've found use mysql_query but I want to use mysqli.

```
<?php
$con=mysqli_connect("localhost","","","");
// Check connection
if (mysqli_connect_errno())
  {
  echo "Failed to connect to MySQL: " . mysqli_connect_error();
  }

$sql="INSERT INTO entry (firstname, lastname, emailaddress, favoritesong) VALUES ('$_POST[firstname]','$_POST[lastname]','$_POST[emailaddress]','$_POST[favoritesong]')";

if (!mysqli_query($con,$sql))
  {
  die('Error: ' . mysqli_error($con));
  }
echo "1 record added";

mysqli_close($con);
?>
```

Comment: Make `emailaddress` as `UNIQUE KEY` in database.

Comment: What is the prinmary key(s) of the `entry` table, if it has one/some? None, autoincrement, or emailaddress or other?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**WARNING!** the posted code and this answer (as i am only addressing the question now) contain big SQL injection leaks. Please read up on SQL injection and use escaping or prepared statements.

```
<?php

$con = mysqli_connect("localhost", "", "", "");
// Check connection
if (mysqli_connect_errno()) {
    echo "Failed to connect to MySQL: " . mysqli_connect_error();
    exit();
}
$existsQuery = "select count(*) as count from entry where emailaddress like '".$_POST[emailaddress]."'";
$existsResult = mysqli_query($con, $existsQuery);

if($existsResult->fetch_object()->count > 0)
{
    echo "email already exist";
}
else
{
    $sql = "INSERT INTO entry (firstname, lastname, emailaddress, favoritesong) VALUES ('$_POST[firstname]','$_POST[lastname]','$_POST[emailaddress]','$_POST[favoritesong]')";

    if (!mysqli_query($con, $sql)) {
        die('Error: ' . mysqli_error($con));
    }
    echo "1 record added";
}

mysqli_close($con);
?>
```

Comment: Considering my knowledge with PHP and MySQL is very little. What are the actual risks of using this code on a live website?

Comment: they could alter your DB, retrieve data from your DB, etc. It if really a very high risk leak. here you can find the simplest solution: http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.real-escape-string.php

Comment: @nvanesch It's still interesting to note that `mysqli_query` takes measures to prevent SQL Injection e.g. "An extra API call is used for multiple statements to reduce the likeliness of accidental SQL injection attacks." If a second statement was injected, the call would fail, using `mysqli_query`.

Comment: It is correct that they try to prevent accidental injection, but sometimes i wish they wouldn't. Now some people think they don't have to be as carefull als mysqli_ handles it. But with the insert query in my answer i would be able to output all other table's data into this entry table. if this is for example a message shown on a site i am able to view all data i want. so also user data, payment data, etc. and there are also dozens of other ways to make good use of the mysqli_ injection possibilities.

Answer (score 1):

simply make `emailaddress` `unique` in your table.

Comment: `if (!mysqli_query($con,$sql))
  {
    echo "email already exists";
  } else {
echo "1 record added"; }
`

Comment: This way any error thrown by this query will make the user think the email address exists. Should it fail over any other reason, it will be a hard to debug and incomprehensible piece.